# Cluster Analysis on GPS data - Assigning GPS coordinates to core groups

Tags: clustering, k-nearest-neighbour

I'm trying to figure out a way to assign GPS coordinates to core GPS values.

For example,

I've got tons of store locations (with long & lat coordinates) and I'd like to group them to one of x core GPS groups (cities).

I know how to perform a k-means cluster analysis and let the algorithm identify the clusters itself, but in this case I know how many groups I need and where I'd like their centers to be.

Is there a way I can use the K-NN algorithm to automatically associate GPS coordinates to group centers defined by the user?

Thanks,

PS. I currently program in Stata, but if this task is easier in either Python, R, or SAS, please feel free to post how.

Comment: k-means in its basic form cannot decide on k (you decide on it).

Answer (score 3):

When you predefine the "clusters" this is called **classification**.

Use nearest neighbor classification to map each user to the nearest city.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So if establishing city GPS coordinates is how I define the clusters, is there any tutorial on how to do this and with which program would this be easiest to do?

Comment: It's so basic, you do not need any program at all. But "nearest neighbor classification" is the search term you need.